# SPARQL query not displaying results

Tags: sparql, owl, virtuoso

I'm very new to Semantic Web programming. I have an OWL file that I've loaded into Virtuoso server at the URI `http://myexample.com`. Now when I open the Virtuoso SPARQL query editor (`http://localhost:8890/sparql`), and run the following query, I get no results:

```
SELECT ?class FROM <myexample.com> WHERE{?class a owl:class} Order By ?class
```

Here is my OWL file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY owl2xml "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl2-xml#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
<!ENTITY Antibiotics "http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#" >
<!ENTITY Antibiotics2 "http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#2" >
<!ENTITY Antibiotics3 "http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#1" >
<!ENTITY Antibiotics4 "http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#3" >
<!ENTITY Traveler "http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Traveler&#39;" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl2xml="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl2-xml#"
     xmlns:Antibiotics2="&Antibiotics;2"
     xmlns:Traveler="&Antibiotics;Traveler&#39;"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
          xmlns:Antibiotics="http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#"
     xmlns:Antibiotics3="&Antibiotics;1"
     xmlns:Antibiotics4="&Antibiotics;3">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about=""/>



    <!-- 
          ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#cures_disease -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#cures_disease">
        <rdfs:label>cures_disease</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Antibiotics"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Diseases"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#has_SideEffects -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#has_SideEffects">
        <rdfs:label>has_SideEffects</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Antibiotics"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#SideEffects"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#1st_Generation -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#1st_Generation">
        <rdfs:label>1st_Generation</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Antibiotics"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#2nd_Generation -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#2nd_Generation">
        <rdfs:label>2nd_Generation</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Antibiotics"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#3rd_Generation -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#3rd_Generation">
        <rdfs:label>3rd_Generation</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Antibiotics"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Aminopenicillins -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Aminopenicillins">
        <rdfs:label
            >Aminopenicillins</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Antibiotics"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Antibiotics -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Antibiotics">
        <rdfs:label>Antibiotics</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Diseases -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Diseases">
        <rdfs:label>Diseases</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Lincosamide -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Lincosamide">
        <rdfs:label>Lincosamide</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Antibiotics"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#SideEffects -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#SideEffects">
        <rdfs:label>SideEffects</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&owl;Thing"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Acne -->

    <Diseases rdf:about="#Acne">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
        <rdfs:label>Acne</rdfs:label>
    </Diseases>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Allergic_Reactions -->

    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Allergic_Reactions">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#SideEffects"/>
        <rdfs:label
            >Allergic_Reactions</rdfs:label>
    </owl:Thing>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Amoxicillin -->

    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Amoxicillin">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Aminopenicillins"/>
        <rdfs:label>Amoxicillin</rdfs:label>
        <has_SideEffects rdf:resource="#Diarrhea"/>
        <cures_disease rdf:resource="#Wide_Range_Of_Infections"/>
    </owl:Thing>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Cefalexin -->

    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Cefalexin">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#1st_Generation"/>
        <rdfs:label>Cephalexin</rdfs:label>
        <cures_disease rdf:resource="#Gram_positive_infections"/>
        <has_SideEffects rdf:resource="#Nausea"/>
    </owl:Thing>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Cefazolin -->

    <Antibiotics3:st_Generation rdf:about="#Cefazolin">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
        <rdfs:label>Cefazolin</rdfs:label>
        <has_SideEffects rdf:resource="#Allergic_Reactions"/>
        <cures_disease rdf:resource="#Gram_positive_infections"/>
    </Antibiotics3:st_Generation>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Cefepime -->

    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Cefepime">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#3rd_Generation"/>
        <rdfs:label>Cefepime</rdfs:label>
        <has_SideEffects rdf:resource="#Nausea"/>
        <cures_disease rdf:resource="#Pseudomonal_Infections"/>
    </owl:Thing>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Cefoxitin -->

    <Antibiotics2:nd_Generation rdf:about="#Cefoxitin">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
        <rdfs:label>Cefoxitin</rdfs:label>
        <has_SideEffects rdf:resource="#Allergic_Reactions"/>
        <cures_disease rdf:resource="#Gram_negative_cover"/>
    </Antibiotics2:nd_Generation>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Clindamycin -->

    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Clindamycin">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Lincosamide"/>
        <rdfs:label>Clindamycin</rdfs:label>
        <cures_disease rdf:resource="#Acne"/>
        <has_SideEffects rdf:resource="#Diarrhea"/>
    </owl:Thing>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Diarrhea -->

    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Diarrhea">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#SideEffects"/>
        <rdfs:label>Diarrhea</rdfs:label>
    </owl:Thing>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Gastrointestinal_Upset -->

    <SideEffects rdf:about="#Gastrointestinal_Upset">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
        <rdfs:label
            >Gastrointestinal_Upset</rdfs:label>
    </SideEffects>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Gram_negative_cover -->

    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Gram_negative_cover">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Diseases"/>
        <rdfs:label
            >Gram_negative_cover</rdfs:label>
    </owl:Thing>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Gram_positive_infections -->

    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Gram_positive_infections">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Diseases"/>
        <rdfs:label
            >Gram_positive_infections</rdfs:label>
        <cures_disease rdf:resource="#Gram_positive_infections"/>
        <has_SideEffects rdf:resource="#Nausea"/>
    </owl:Thing>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Nausea -->

    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Nausea">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#SideEffects"/>
        <rdfs:label>Nausea</rdfs:label>
    </owl:Thing>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Pseudomonal_Infections -->

    <Diseases rdf:about="#Pseudomonal_Infections">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
        <rdfs:label
            >Pseudomonal_Infections</rdfs:label>
    </Diseases>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Wide_Range_Of_Infections -->

    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Wide_Range_Of_Infections">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Diseases"/>
        <rdfs:label
            >Wide_Range_Of_Infections</rdfs:label>
    </owl:Thing>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // General axioms
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    <rdf:Description>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
        <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Antibiotics"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Diseases"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="#SideEffects"/>
        </owl:members>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
        <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="#1st_Generation"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="#2nd_Generation"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="#3rd_Generation"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Aminopenicillins"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Lincosamide"/>
        </owl:members>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 2.2.1.1138) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IRIs are case sensitive.  Notice that in your ontology **owl:Class** uses a majuscule **C**:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="#1st_Generation">
    <rdfs:label>1st_Generation</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Antibiotics"/>
</owl:Class>
```

That needs to be the case in your SPARQL query as well.  And, if you haven't elsewhere, you'll need to define the prefix.  If you stored the data in a graph named http://myexample.com, then you might need to select from that, exactly, with **from <http://myexample.com>**. Don't drop the **http://** prefix.  I downloaded your data, and this query produces the following results:

```sql
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

select ?class where {
  ?class a owl:Class
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| class                                                                                     |
=============================================================================================
| owl:Thing                                                                                 |
| <http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#SideEffects>      |
| <http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Lincosamide>      |
| <http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Diseases>         |
| <http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Antibiotics>      |
| <http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#Aminopenicillins> |
| <http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#3rd_Generation>   |
| <http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#2nd_Generation>   |
| <http://www.semanticweb.org/uthejsree/ontologies/2014/8/Antibiotics.owl#1st_Generation>   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It still does not give me any results.

Comment: I saved your data and ran that SPARQL query against it and got the results that I've shown.  The `FROM <myexample.com>` in your query is suspect.  If you have a graph named `http://myexample.com`, then you'd use `FROM <http://myexample.com>`.  Don't drop the `http://` prefix.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. Is there any reason why I shouldn't drop the `http://` prefix? I'm new to Semantic Web programming. And I'd like to know the reason behind this.

Comment: @user2201650 "Is there any reason why I shouldn't drop the http:// prefix?"  Yes, a very important one. :)  `http://myexample.com` is a IRI and, as such, can be used to name a graph that you can query.  `myexample.com` isn't (or maybe it's a relative one).  IRIs sometimes begin with `http://`, but they don't always.  E.g., `urn:ex:foo` is an IRI.  So is `mailto:joe@example.com`.  Now, it's true that the SPARQL grammar allows you to write `FROM <myexample.com>`, (IRIREF is defined as ``'<' ([^<>"{}|^`\]-[#x00-#x20])* '>'``), but even so `http://myexample.com` and `myexample.com` are different.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks a lot for taking out time and explaining it to me :)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I have one more question. Is it possible to access an ontology server from within a SPARQL query? I'm basically the same question as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842339/is-it-possible-to-read-an-ontology-from-a-sparql-endpoint

Comment: Look into the **service** keyword.  E.g., `select * where { ... service <http://...> { ... } ... }`.  It's typically called a federated query.  The spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) is fairly readable;  it's a good idea to skim through it to get an idea of what's in the language. You can return to it later when you need the specific details.  (This is good advice in general; it's a good idea to *skim* the manual or documentation when you start using a new tool so that you have a rough idea what's available.  Then you can go back for details when you actually need that functionality.)